# How to get value at the ng-model for the options under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let my HTML is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
<select  ng-model="myselect">  
     <option value="">{{option.attribute_text}}:</option>
     <option value="">{{option.attr_value}}-${{option.cost}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I want to get the values of the option selected in the ng-model. Is there any methods to get the values in the `ng-model` under a `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple selects and you are giving same model to all of them.
you can't give them same `myselect` to all of them.

give each option(the ones you are repeating) a name, and use an object's keys for their model.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
  <select  ng-model="selections[option.name]">  
     <option value="">{{option.attribute_text}}:</option>
     <option value="">{{option.attr_value}}-${{option.cost}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

then you can access them like `$scope.selections["some option name you gave earlier"]`

Comment: But the ng-model inside the ng-repeat is not working.how to display the values of the options in the model?

Comment: `<option value="this is the value that will be assigned to model">`.
Also are you sure you need multiple comboxes or one combobox with may options?

Comment: My requirement is to display data in multiple dropdown boxes.Also i want to know how data binding happens on ng-model undermultiple selection in ng-repeat?

Comment: It happens the same way as everywhere else. For select's your models are set to selected `option`'s `value` fields. And in your example they are all empty. If you can create a fiddle with the code you tried in the question i could help and understand your question more.

Comment: Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tincymary/x2hA4/16/ i want to select all the options and also want to get the value of the selected options in ng-model.

Comment: you probably want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/x2hA4/40/

if so, tell me and ask if anything is unclear and i will update my answer clearing those out.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use select you can use [ng-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

if you specify `ng-model` for `ng-select` it bind the select option to `ng-model`

you can see it in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mewez/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Here's an example that should be about right:

Options stored as list of hashes in your controller:

```
   $scope.options = [ { "attribute_text" : "whatever", "data" : { "value" : 9, "cost" : 8 }, { ... } ]
   // Selected value
   $scope.optionSelected = {};
```

HTML:

```
<div>
   <select ng-select="option.attribute_text for option in options" ng-model="optionSelected">
</div>
```